# How can I set last month on datetimepicker bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I try like this :

```
var lastMonth = new Date();
lastMonth.setMonth(lastMonth.getMonth() - 1 );
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    defaultDate: lastMonth
});
```

It works

But in the datetimepicker bootstrap plugin, whether there are methods that can be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    defaultDate: moment(12, "MM");
});
```

This line of code will set the current year and last month by default:

```
moment(3, "MM");
```

Also make sure you have `momentjs` library referenced.

Comment: Great. I try : `defaultDate: moment(new Date()).subtract(1,'months')`. It works. Thanks